# FPGA be automatically programmed?

Tags: fpga, hardware-acceleration

Can FPGAs be automatically programmed to accelerate arbitrary software or is manual work required?  I imagine there's nothing inherently stopping this from being possible - I'm just curious if it's currently possible as that could be a nice way to do hardware acceleration assuming the cost made sense.

Comment: Define automatic as opposed to manual? FPGAs are programmed using pre-prepared binary files - a controlling software application could be implemented to have the intelligence to know when to configure, how to configure and how to communicate with the FPGA ... so yes. Back in the good old days, when money was plucked from trees...we had FPGAs reprogramming other FPGAs...magic...look no software!

Comment: @fpga_magik it could be that I don't know much about how FPGAs work, but what I was hoping for is to take an arbitrary Windows program and tell the FPGA (or something else) to program the FPGA automatically such that that program is now accelerated.  Please forgive if I'm butchering the wording, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: there are frameworks available where code from a particular language can be _automatically_ taken to FPGA (synthesised+implemented) but the extent of the design is **very** limited and closed off (remember its hardware!). And there are other considerations that are prevalent due to the nature of hardware - so as mentioned below, **no**!

Answer (score 1):

One of the techniques (available for Xilinx FPGAs for example) is the PR (Partial Reconfiguration).
**Partial Reconfiguration** is the ability to dynamically modify blocks of logic by downloading partial bit files while the remaining logic continues to operate without interruption. Xilinx Partial Reconfiguration technology allows designers to change functionality on the fly, eliminating the need to fully reconfigure and re-establish links, dramatically enhancing the flexibility that FPGAs offer. The use of Partial Reconfiguration can allow designers to move to fewer or smaller devices, reduce power, and improve system upgradability. Make more efficient use of the silicon by only loading in functionality that is needed at any point in time.

Anyway, in the literature, you can find a lot of other differents example and differents strategy and techniques to change, runtime and automatically, the FPGA configuration. This gives the possibility (for an autonomous system) to evolve and to adapt themselves to several contexts. You can find a a tool for the design of dynamically Reconfigurable Embedded and Modular Systems [Here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6416740/) and [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6494560/) you can find an example.

*

### **Key Technology Benefits**

*

- Increase solution flexibility by time-multiplexing design functionality
- Reduce FPGA size or count (and therefore cost) by time-sharing functionality
- Reduce dynamic power consumption by loading functions on-demand

Comment: Partial reconfiguration has always been very difficult to work with and we've always found that its only really practical for small devices and/or simple scaled up designs in larger devices (if that makes sense!). Which is why, in my other comment, we resorted to going through with the easier approach of using more than one device. Of course, I haven't used it in many years so it might be smoothened out.